# Using a split formula in Excel with inconsistent data, as we do in Google sheets

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

We want to migrate some spreadsheets from Google sheets to Excel. We figured out how to manage all the needed formulas, except one: `SPLIT`.

Here is a public view link to a sample file, which shows you how we currently do this in Google sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D1ceuF28CqMtr0tEPdAQNLSvvuFMFAQE54fopS2wvAo/edit?usp=sharing

Column B contains, for each record, a list of the record's favorite charitable causes, such as Animal welfare, Cancer, Digital divide, Environment, Human Rights, Hunger, Medical research, etc. A cell in that column might contain no content, one cause, or as many as 16 causes, each on a separate line within that cell. The Google delimiter for those line breaks within a cell is "char(10)." (I do not know if Excel uses the same for a line break).

In Google sheets, our formula in column C is
`=if(len(B2)=0,"",split(B2,char(10)))`. The first part just makes sure that we do not get a #VALUE error if the cell is empty.

We are familiar with the 'Text to Columns' menu options, but we need a formula in column C such that everything gets updated automatically whenever the content of column B is changed; we cannot do it manually each time.

Please note that the number of entries in column B is inconsistent, as is the length of each element.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBsWb.png)

=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B2,UNICHAR(10),REPT(" ",LEN($B2))),(C$1-1)*LEN($B2)+1,LEN($B2)))

B2 is the cell with your array.
UNICHAR(10) is newline.
C1 is the index.

The formula splits up the array by newline character, just like in your google sheet  which uses CHAR(10). Then, it uses C1, to identify which item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 `=TEXTSPLIT(B2,CHAR(10))`

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer to be the one that helped you, please accept the answer, or upvote.